# Nodemcu firmware cannot resolve DNS or use http client. But it connects to a working Wi-Fi access point.

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I can connect to AP using the default init.lua from readthedocs. -- https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/upload/

But DNS does not work and neither does http client.

I edited credentials.lua to match my SSID and password. It successfully connects to my WiFi

I verify it is connected with this example script:

```
do
local sta_config=wifi.sta.getconfig(true)
print(string.format("\tCurrent station config\n\tssid:\"%s\"\tpassword:\"%s\"\n\tbssid:\"%s\"\tbssid_set:%s", sta_config.ssid, sta_config.pwd, sta_config.bssid, (sta_config.bssid_set and "true" or "false")))
end
```

Results:

```
[NodeMCU-Tool] Connected
[NodeMCU] Version: 2.2.0 | ChipID: 0x813d2b | FlashID: 0x1625c2
[NodeMCU] Running "getapinfo.lua"
[NodeMCU] >----------------------------->
Current station config
    ssid:"JohnnyCinco"  password:"88888888"
    bssid:"00:05:4e:4c:3e:0b"   bssid_set:false
[NodeMCU] >----------------------------->
```

I verify I get an IP using this example script.

```
ip, nm, gw = wifi.sta.getip()
print("IP Address is:")
print(ip)
print("NM is:")
print(nm)
print("GW Address is:")
print(gw)
```

Results:

```
IP Address is:
192.168.61.197
NM is:
255.255.255.0
GW Address is:
192.168.61.1
```

This is the correct IP for this router.

But a simple DNS fails. I created a script with the example from nodemcu.

```
net.dns.resolve("www.google.com", function(sk, ip)
    if (ip == nil) then print("DNS fail!") else print(ip) end
end)
```

This is the result.

```
[NodeMCU-Tool] Connected
[NodeMCU] Version: 2.2.0 | ChipID: 0x813d2b | FlashID: 0x1625c2
[NodeMCU] Running "getgoogdns.lua"
[NodeMCU] >----------------------------->
null
[NodeMCU] >----------------------------->
```

Even though I get a DNS server from DHCP. I changed it to 8.8.8.8 to test again and I get the same failure.

I can create a http server and hit it from other WiFi clients on the LAN, that part works. But DNS lookups and http client requests all fail.

This WiFi AP works for all other clients. There is no firewall. Just to be sure I tried 2 different routers. I also tried a 3rd router that has cellular Internet instead of my cable internet. All fail.

This is on nodemcu version 2.2.0. I have tried both dev and master branches. Same results on both.

I have tried building on nodemcu-build.com and also built on my own linux machine. Both fail.

I have tried 4 different ESP8266 dev boards from different providers. All fail.

What am I missing? I must be missing something basic. This is too basic to be broken. Or is latest firmware broken?

Thanks
J5

Comment: "This is too basic to be broken" - indeed, I just confirmed it (still) works. Do you get the expected results from `net.dns.getdnsserver(0)` and `net.dns.getdnsserver(1)`?

Comment: Yes I have tried setting both DNS 0 and 1 to different servers and they all fail. All http client gets fail as well. This seems so basic. I just do a build on the build cloud, then put on the init.lua file and credentials. It connects, gets an IP over WPA2, shows connected as a client on my router, but I cannot do a DNS lookup or http get on anything. I have tried 3 routers, 2 on my cable internet and 1 LTE router. -- When you tested, is that from a fresh build from the nodemcu-build.com? Or an older build? - I tried 4 ESP8266 as well. -- Anything else to check why these all return null?

Comment: I tested this simple Gist against the current `master`: https://gist.github.com/marcelstoer/7ae3e19c7be2847530fa63433637de60 Can you maybe try with a firmware that has debug enabled?

Comment: I did a new build on nodemcu-build of master with only default modules checked. Enabled debug. Erased flash, flashed with new bin. The init.lua you linked does not connect. I changed 1st 2 lines to correct SSID/pass. But it stays in mode 1, trying to connect. Used other init.lua from upload page with credentials file. It connects. There is no new information when I run dns lookup example. It still just says null. What is debugging supposed to say? I have esptool version v2.4.0-dev and flash according to nodemcu docs. Not sure what else to check.

Comment: Marcel, what version of esptool are you using. This version seems to be their master version in github. I have swapped out boards (dev kits) and usb cables as well. Thanks again, and again this seems too basic. But I have been at this for weeks.

Comment: I use my own NodeMCU PyFlasher: https://github.com/marcelstoer/nodemcu-pyflasher

Comment: I gave up on flashing and uploading files from Ubuntu 18.04. I switched to a Windows computer and used pyflasher to flash the firmware and ESPlorer to upload files. Works great. Finally get to play with it. So there must be some issue with flashing and/or uploading files from Ubuntu 18.04 that somehw corrupts the files. I tried multiple versions of esptool.py to load fw. And nodemcu-uploader and also tried nodemcu-tool. Somehow between these I got the results from my initial post. Switched to Windows and it works. Thanks for help Marcel. Can't wait to try out the nodemcu firmware.

Comment: Glad it works. Sounds rather like an issue with the driver on Ubuntu (USB-serial).

Comment: Issue exists with Mac 10.14.4 too. I was about to give it up entirely, guess I'll try windows!